# Need a little help getting Windows Phone SDK to work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Why is trying to use the Windows Phone SDK (Any version) so problematic? I have tried to install WP8 on my Windows 8 machine with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and despite a month of troubleshooting and searching, not a single thing has fixed the issue. First of all, the WP8 installer tells me that my OS is not Windows 8 - then it tells me that my version of the .NET Framework is not supported (I have every version from 3.0 up to 4.5). As a last resort, I tried running the installer in compatibility mode but that option is not even available for the installer.

And then I looked in my Start menu and found a folder named Visual Studio 2010 Express. I expanded this folder and to my surprise, it had Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone.Ink (WP7.0 and WP7.1) in there - so I opened it. Everything seemed to be going just fine. I created a new project "PhoneApp1" and without writing any code or making any changes, I hit the debug button - and this is what I get:

[image]

It says "Run the program without getting help". So I clicked it. And then this happens:

[image]

Click OK...

[image]

Click NO...

[image]

> Connection failed because of invalid command line arguments.

Now we get the error message. Not very helpful, but I went searching online and I dug as deep as I could in Google results and I think I've tried atleast 20 different sites and even more "solutions" but not a single one of the solutions even worked.

Hass anybody had this exact same issue? How did you fix it?

Please don't tell me to install WP8 SDK unless you also have a solution that works for that.

Comment: If you run CMD, what's your version of Windows?

Comment: @Martheen it says [Version 6.2.8400] - I am running Windows 8 Release Preview. Build 8400.

Comment: Hah. I knew it. All those Aero and start button... None of them in RTM. Well, the current SDK is not designed for Windows 8 preview release.

Comment: Ok @Martheen I will go and get myself a nice shiny new copy of Win8! Been a bit too lazy to get one lately. The Start button though - not a part of Windows 8 release preview, I got it back by using StarDock's Start8 program lol

Comment: Sorry, turns out it must be Windows 8 Pro and above, and it should be an x64 edition http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to install win8 ultimate，because i think wp8 is just compatible with win 8 RTM.
about wp7,i have no idea, but win 8 is compatible with those wp7 and wp8

Comment: Thanks @King - I'm not sure if we can get Win8 ultimate over here. The ony verison I've seen in the shops is Windows 8 Pro...

Comment: Developing WP8 would only require Windows 8 RTM, any edition will do the job. Oh, and your CPU must support SLAT http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2012/10/24/hyper-v-list-of-slat-capable-cpus-for-hosts.aspx since WP8 emulator uses Hyper-V. Do note you'll lose access to the interface (but not the functionality) of Power Management when Hyper-V is active http://superuser.com/questions/510243/why-doesnt-windows-8-task-manager-report-the-actual-cpu-frequency-when-virtuali

Answer (score 0):

The Best solution is to install Windows 8 Pro or higher and install either WP SDK 8 or 7.1. You can have both VS versions side by side.

And if that is not possible right now, for time being your problem may be solved by installing [Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233). Which makes the WP 7.1 SDK compatible with Windows 8 And also adds the Emulator supprot for 256MB RAM devices. Your screen shot indicates that you did not have this 7.1.1 update.